# Different versions for the Radial Solution of the Hydrogen Atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, atomic-physics, orbitals

Initially, I'm trying to prove if the following is true

$$|\psi_{n00}(r=0)|^2 =\dfrac{1}{\pi n^3a_0^3}$$

I'm looking to solve some calculations made in

Introductory Quantum Optics
Christopher Gerry Lehman College, City University of New York
Peter Knight Imperial College London and UK National Physical Laboratory

and in the section  2.6, page 31, the past equation is numbered as $(2.164)$. Even as I tried to do all the math behind it, i'm not reaching the said result.

The hydrogen atom solution is

$$\psi_{nlm_l}=R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$$

One of the radial solutions I've found is

$$R_{nl}(r)=-\left(\dfrac{2}{na_0}\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{(n-l-1)!}{2n[(n+l)!]^3}}\left(\dfrac{2r}{na_0}\right)^le^{-r/na_0}L_{n-\ell-1}^{2l+1}\left(\dfrac{2r}{na_0}\right)$$

This radial solution is the one found in Sakurai, Zetilli, Messiah, and many others. Only the one from Wikipedia gives the result I'm trying to prove, which is

$$\psi_{n \ell m}(r, \theta, \varphi) = \sqrt{{\left( \frac{2}{n a^*_0} \right)}^3 \frac{(n - \ell - 1)!}{2 n (n + \ell)!}} e^{-\rho / 2} \rho^{\ell} L_{n - \ell - 1}^{2 \ell + 1}(\rho) Y_\ell^m (\theta, \varphi)$$

As seen, the associated Laguerre polynomials are different and the denominator of the root is also different. What makes them different? Is there any paper or book where I can corroborate the Wikipedia's expression?

Comment: In the first equation, you wrote the magnitude of $\psi$, i.e., $|\psi|$. Did you mean to write $|\psi|^2$?

Comment: @hft Yes! Missed the ^2 hehe, thanks!

Comment: Are you using that book’s definition of the associated Laguerre polynomials? If not, your problem is probably just inconsistent conventions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Physicist_Scaling_Convention

Comment: @Ghoster It is that the book that I use does not bring the definitions of the polynomials. Just recite the equation, I'm using the definition I find because the book doesn't say anything.

Comment: Then you have to figure out which convention it is using, and apparently it is not the one you found. Wikipedia says there are *three* conventions. See if one of them works. Or use a better source which actually defines all the special functions that it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you've got the wrong expression for the wavefunction, the factor with the Lagurre polynomial should be
$$L^{2l+1}_{n-l-1}(0),$$
for $l=0$ this reduces to $$L^{1}_{n-1}(0)=n$$
and so $$|\psi_{n,0,0}(0)|^2=\left(\frac{2}{n a_0}\right)^3 \frac{1}{2n^2}n^2\frac{1}{4\pi}=\frac{1}{\pi a_0^3 n^3} $$

Comment: Yes, fixed the typo

Comment: By solving the square root I get a $1/n(n!)$ using the definition that $n!=n(n-1)!$ and I don't get the result

Comment: I used the expression given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if the following is true

> $|\psi_{n00}(r=0)|^2 =\dfrac{1}{\pi n^3a_0^3}$

Assuming $\psi$ is a hydrogen electron wavefunction then yes, it is true.

Comment: But, how could you prove it mathematically?

Comment: @Ghoster I've modified as suggested, thanks for the clarification!